# Wait on two asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-visualization

The problem I have is that I want to draw a chart based on the data returned from fetch. I know that I could do the following

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    // get the data and draw the chart after
    fetch(url).then...
}
```

but, I would like to do something like this

```
// load google charts
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(???);
// get the data
fetch(url).???;

// a function that runs after both are complete
drawsChartsAfterBothComplete();
```

that way the data and the google library can load asynchronously and one doesn't have to wait on the other. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it in my scenario? Thanks

**Edit:**

I've determined there is no need to use `setOnLoadCallback()` and that `load()` returns a promise thanks to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is probably what you are looking for.

You can run both of those in promises, and run the draw function after they complete.

```
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // load google charts here
}); 

var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // fetch here
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(values => { 
  drawsChartsAfterBothComplete();
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway you could give an example? I've seen Promise.all() but I didn't see a way to use it with the `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback()`

Comment: You don't need callbacks anymore using the promise above.

Comment: Oops, just saw you edit that before I commented, glad you figured it out first!

Comment: It's not explicit yet in the answer that calling google.charts.load() returns a promise.  Most simply, you would have to use that promise instead of p1 like this: Promise.all([google.charts.load(...), p2]).  Or you could call the resolve function of p1 { google.charts.load(...).then(() => resolve()) } or just pass the resolve function to the callback: { google.charts.load('current', { packages: [...], callback: resolve }) }